# Using logical OR operator in condition

Tags: ruby, boolean

my code is comparing a strings "text" against two additional strings "redact" and "redact2" and replacing it with "REDACTED" if there is match.

```
puts "Enter your sentense"
text = gets.downcase.chomp

puts "Enter your 2 words to be reducted"
redact = gets.downcase.chomp
redact2 = gets.downcase.chomp

words = text.split(" ")

words.each do |w|
    if w == redact
        print "REDACTED "
    elsif
        w == redact2
        print "REDACTED "
    else
        print w + " "
    end
end
```

I was trying to simplify my code by using logical OR in `if` statement, but the code prints `"RETUCTED"` for all words. Can someone please explain me why?

```
words.each do |w|
    if w == redact || redact2
        print "REDACTED "
    else
        print w + " "
    end
end
```

Comment: hey, make sure to select the answer that solves your problem best and accept it (look for a ckeckmark near the anwer score)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can someone please explain me why?

Because `==` binds stronger, than `||`.

Thus, your statement is actually interpreted as follows:

```
if (w == redact) || redact2
```

not as you are expecting:

```
if w == (redact || redact2)
```

To solve it you have few options:

- `if w == redact || w == redact2`
- `if [reduct, reduct2].include?(w)`

If you are keen on saving few more lines, you could have simplified your code to:

```
words.each do |w|
  print [redact,redact2].include?(w) ? "REDACTED " : w + " "
end
```

Answer (score 1):

or tries to operate on two boolean values.
You give it `w=="redact"` which is a boolean and `"redact2` which is a string (evaluates to true).

What you actually want to do is `if w == redact || w == redact2`.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko Didn't meant compare. You're right. Your answer is actually also wrong. == binds stronger than ||.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko Gotta need those 50 rep to comment... :'(

Comment: @AndreyDeineko Would've told you sooner.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko Actually even then your answer is wrong. `w == ("a" || "b")` would be true if w was true...

Comment: actually nope :) `true == ('a' || 'b')` => `false`

Comment: @AndreyDeineko Oh really? does `"a" == ("a"||"b")` work then? Or is it false?

Comment: didn't get where this one goes, but `"a" == ("a"||"b")` => `true`, isn't it suppose to be so? :)

Comment: @AndreyDeineko Ah ofc! `"b"==("a"||"b") => false`. "a" is truthy so it gets returned. If the first value is falsy (false or nil) the second one gets returned.